# Joda Time Not getting expected result

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a date string of format `MM/dd/yyyy` that I am parsing using `SimpleDateFormat`

Now say the `startDateString` is `11/26/2012` for the code given below. I set the time zone to **America/New_York**

```
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Date st = df.parse(startDateString);

Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

System.out.println("BEFORE : Start Date :"+startDate.getTime());

startDate.setTime(st);

System.out.println("AFTER : Start Date :"+startDate.getTime());

DateTimeZone timezone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");

DateTime actualStartDate = new DateTime(startDate,timezone);

System.out.println("JODA DATE TIME "+ actualStartDate);
```

The outout of above code snippet:

```
BEFORE : Start Date :Tue Nov 27 12:26:51 IST 2012

AFTER : Start Date :Mon Nov 26 00:00:00 IST 2012 //ok it sets date to 26th
                                                 //with all time parameters as 0.

JODA DATE TIME 2012-11-25T13:30:00.000-05:00 // here the date and 
                                             // time parameter are changed
```

What my problem is when I create my `actualStartDate` like this :

```
DateTime actualStartDate = new DateTime(startDate,timezone);
```

The date changes to 25 and the time changes to 13:00:00
I think this is because of timezone zone difference between India and US (total -10:30 from IST Indian time)

What I want is `JODA DATE TIME 2012-11-26T00:00:00.000-05:00`

Do I manually set the parameters of time inside my `startDate` calendar instance to `0` ?

Comment: Please change your code to be complete - you haven't shown the time zone for your `SimpleDateFormat`, which could easily be relevant. Even if it proves not to be, it makes it harder to go through what's happening without that information. It would be handy if you'd give us an example we could run completely ourselves.

Comment: Additionally, why are you mixing `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar` and Joda Time? Why not do *everything* in Joda Time?

Comment: @JonSkeet edited with date format code, I just started using joda time so I am not aware of all the stuff

Comment: See my answer - basically, your problems aren't with Joda Time at all; they're with your code using `SimpleDateFormat`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're *parsing* in your default time zone. This:

```
AFTER : Start Date :Mon Nov 26 00:00:00 IST 2012
```

shows that the instant in time you're using is midnight *IST* - not midnight in New York or in UTC. Currently IST is 18:30 in UTC, so the instant you're representing is 25-11-25T18:30:00Z.

When you convert that into New York time, you end up with 2012-11-25T13:30:00-05:00, which is exactly what Joda Time is doing.

I would strongly advise that:

- You avoid using the Java libraries at all (that's where all the problems have come from here - both in parsing, and the result of `Date.toString()` confusing you)
- You use `LocalDate` to represent a date, rather than `DateTime`. You're trying to represent a *date* after all, not an instant in time. This bypasses time zones entirely, as a date doesn't *have* a time zone.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String text = "11/26/2012";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
                          .withLocale(Locale.US);

        LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate(text);
        System.out.println(date);
    }    
}
```

Once you've *got* a `LocalDate`, if you want to find out the instant at which that day started in a particular time zone, you can use [`LocalDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29).